# Running project with Qt includes in Visual Studio express 2008

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2008

I'm still a newbie at this so please bear with me :)

I just got a vs 2008 project that has a few qt includes, namely qtGUI. Now I downloaded the open source pre-built libraries (version 4.8.3) from the qt-project.org site. I've added the include and lib directories under vs2008, but my project still won't compile. I'm getting a few LNK 2001 unresolved external symbol errors. Could someone tell me what I'm missing here?

The specific errors:

```
treeview.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public:static struct QMetaObject const    cQtTreeWidgetFilter::staticMetaObject"(?staticMetaObject@cQtTreeWidgetFilter@@2UQMetaObject@@B)
treeview.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public:virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall    cQtTreeWidgetFilter::metaObject(void)const "    (?metaObject@cQtTreeWidgetFilter@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
treeview.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public:virtual void * __thiscall cQtTreeWidgetFilter::qt_metacast(char const    *)" (?qt_metacast@cQtTreeWidgetFilter@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)
treeview.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int    __thiscall cQtTreeWidgetFilter::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)"    (?qt_metacall@cQtTreeWidgetFilter@@UAEHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z)
```

Comment: You need to post the specific errors. This is expected to work.

Comment: Added the errors I get, seem to be general link errors. I must be missing something very trivial, an additional dll dependancy or dunno just can't figure it out.

Comment: Looks like you are not including your moc generated source for cQtTreeWidgetFilter in your project.

Comment: That's because I don't have one :). I found a moc.exe in the qt dir,so I presume this is what I have to run with some parameters?

Comment: Does the visual studio addon work with express versions?

Comment: You may be able to use the following: https://code.google.com/p/xr-qt-msvc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of trouble I found a reference in the sdk suggesting that I should downgrade qt to a previous version. I went and downloaded 4.6.2 and now it generates the moc file and compiles without error.

Thanks for the help dreschjerm.